# Getting error when sending an email in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I have an error in Laravel when I am sending an email.

I have a form with a select tag and when I select the user and click submit I need to send him a mail after I select it.

Here is my Controller method:

```
public function store()
{

    $customerId = Input::get('customerid');

    $invoice = New Invoice ;

    $invoice->customerid = Input::get('customerid');

    $invoice->save();

    if ($invoice->save()) {

        $email = Customer::whereRaw(' id = :customer',array('customer'=> $customerId ))->first(array('email'));

        Mail::send('invoices.mail', array($pinvoices,$unpinvoices), function($message) {
            $message->to($email , 'Name')->subject('your invoices ');
        }); 
    }
}
```

**When I click submit I get an error** :

> Undefined variable: email

**and when I tried to add my email as a static value like  :**

```
$email = "myemail@mail.com" ;
     Mail::send('invoices.mail', array($pinvoices,$unpinvoices), function($message){
                $message->to($email , 'Name')->subject('your invoices ');
            });
```

> It's also getting the same error  !!

**and when i put the value like this :**

```
 Mail::send('invoices.mail', array($pinvoices,$unpinvoices), function($message){
            $message->to("myemail@mail.com" , 'Name')->subject('your invoices ');
        });
```

> it works perfectly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closures work just like a regular function. You need to inject your outer scope variables into function's scope.

```
Mail::send('invoices.mail', array($pinvoices,$unpinvoices), function($message) use ($email)
{
    $message->to($email , 'Name')->subject('your invoices ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `$email` parameter in the function

```
$email = "myemail@mail.com" ;
Mail::send('invoices.mail', array('email'=>$email, $pinvoices,$unpinvoices), function($message){
            $message->to($email , 'Name')->subject('your invoices ');
        });
```

Comment: `Mail::send('invoices.mail', array('email'=>$email,'pinvoices'=>$pinvoices,'unpinvoices'=>$unpinvoices), function($message){
        $message->to($email, 'Name')->subject('your invoices ');`

**still undefind variable**

Comment: For instance can you put the `$email` in session and get that session inside the function and try to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable **$email** is not defined within the scope of your **Mail::send** closure. To fix this issue, you should pass the $email variable to the closure using the **use** statement.

```
public function store()
{
    $customerId = Input::get('customerid');

    $invoice = new Invoice;

    $invoice->customerid = Input::get('customerid');

    $invoice->save();

    if ($invoice->save()) {
        // Fetch the customer email
        $email = Customer::whereRaw('id = :customer', ['customer' => $customerId])->first(['email']);

        // Check if the email is found
        if ($email) {
            $pinvoices = /* Logic to get $pinvoices */;
            $unpinvoices = /* Logic to get $unpinvoices */;

            Mail::send('invoices.mail', compact('pinvoices', 'unpinvoices'), function ($message) use ($email) {
                $message->to($email->email, 'Name')->subject('Your invoices');
            });
        }
    }
}
```